# Polymorphism with abstract class

Tags: polymorphism, abstract-class, abstract

A.

```
public abstract class Laptop{
  private int size;
  public int getSize(){
     return size;
  }
  public abstract String getBrand();
}

public class Macbook extends Laptop{
  public int getSize(){
     return 11;
  }
  public String getBrand(){
     return "Apple";
  }}
```

B.

```
public abstract class Laptop{
  private int size;
  public int getSize(){
     return size;
  }
  public abstract String getBrand(){
     return "No name";
  }
}

public class Macbook extends Laptop{
  public int getSize(){
     return 11;
  }
  public String getBrand(){
     return "Apple";
  }}
```

I don't really understand why the code can compile in A but not in B? What is the relationship between polymorphism and abstract classes? Thanks.

Comment: Declare method as ABSTRACT means class only provide the signature not the definition and in class B method getBrand have the method definition which is wrong as per Java contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide implementation to an `abstract` method, as you have in example B:

```
public abstract String getBrand(){
   return "No name";
}
```

Either drop the `abstract` keyword (as it isn't abstract - you're implementing it):

```
public String getBrand(){
   return "No name";
}
```

Or drop the implementation:

```
public abstract String getBrand();
```

Answer (score 0):

Then example B does not compile because you have provided an implementation of an abstract method.

An abstract class is a class that can contain abstract methods which do not have any implementation. The implementation must be supplied by classes that derive from the abstract class.

If you want to provide a default implementation of the method in B, change the declaration of getBrand() in class Laptop from abstract to virtual, and add the keyword 'override' to getBrand() in class Macbook.